# basic_filebuf::sync(): Is this a mistake on cppreference.com?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, filebuf

[The page for `std::basic_filebuf::sync()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/sync) says that

> `sync()` or its equivalent is implicitly called by ... `seekoff()`,
>   and `seekpos()` ...

But I cannot seem to find any mention of this in the language spec, neither [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf) or [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/streambuf).

My read of the `filebuf` portion of the spec for both `seekoff()` and `seekpos()` is that it isn't even clear that they effectively accomplish what `sync()` does (among the other things they're to do), let alone call it *or its equivalent*.

Is this phrasing on *cppreference* a misleading piece of information?

Comment: It's correct afaict.. `close` calls `overflow(traits​::​​eof())` to flush characters.. this is also what `sync` does as well..

Comment: @Brandon Thank you and sorry for including `close()` in the quote. That was my bad. I meant to ask about the *seek* methods. The question is now fixed. My apologies.

Comment: Quoting from the link you gave, both `seekoff` and `seekpos` are specified to "update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence" . That's what the page refers to.

Comment: @Cubbi I fully agree, but `file_buf` is also an input streambuf, and by cppreference.com itself what `sync()` does on the input stream is implementation defined. And the standard for `seekpos` for example states otherwise -- i.e. that the input stream is being synced, not for the implementation to decide.

Comment: @Chubbi as in, excuse the pun, something seemed not enough synced here to me, in this whole thing. That's the reason for the question